# Freeing the previous node in a linked-list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, traversal

I wrote a function to traverse a linked-list, find the node with the smallest value for 'int frequency' and remove that node, once it had traversed the entire list. My error is coming from the node: 'prev'. When I run the code, I get an error saying: "prev is a null pointer". However, if i remove the '= NULL' part from the node declaration, I get a compilation error that says: "prev is uninitialized".

Is this because I need to assign/point prev to one of the existing nodes in the list? If so how would I point it the the node prior to the one I want to delete? (I thought that was done the way it is in my code but obviously not.)

Structure definitions:

```
struct LetterFrequencyPair
{
    char character;
    int frequency;
    //Creating a pointer to point to the next child in the list
    struct BinaryTreeNode* next;
};

struct BinaryTreeNode
{
    //create a pointer to point to the LetterFrequencyPair
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* letter_frequency_pair;
    //create pointers to the children of the node
    struct BinaryTreeNode* leftChild;
    struct BinaryTreeNode* rightChild;
};
```

---

```
struct BinaryTreeNode* ret_lowestF()
{
    int val = 1000;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* temp;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* temp1 = NULL;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* prev = NULL;
    struct LetterFrequencyPair* low = malloc(sizeof(struct 
    LetterFrequencyPair));

    struct BinaryTreeNode* lowest = malloc(sizeof(struct BinaryTreeNode));
    temp = root;
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("%c\t%d\n", temp->character, temp->frequency);

            if (val >> temp->frequency)
            {
                low = temp;
                lowest->letter_frequency_pair = low;
                val = low->frequency;
                temp1 = temp;
                prev->next = temp1;
            }

            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    prev->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    free(temp1);

    printf("lowest frequency node is: %c\t%d\n", low->character, low- 
            >frequency);

    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: `printf("List is empty.\n");` ==> `printf("List is empty.\n"); return NULL;`

Comment: `val >> temp->frequency` Sure you want `>>`?

Comment: You don't move `prev` inside the `while`loop. You need to do that - just like you move `temp`. Something like: `temp = temp->next;`==> `prev = temp; temp = temp->next;`

Comment: @4386427 but I want prev to stay as the node just before the one with the lowest frequency. So as it keeps traversing until the end won't prev keep being moved further down as well?

Comment: It will... so when you find a new lowest value you have to save the value of `prev`.  Like `prev_low = prev;` and at the end you do `prev_low->next = low-> next;` BTW: You don't want `prev->next = temp1;`

Comment: This `lowest->letter_frequency_pair = low;` looks very strange... but since you haven't posted the definition for `struct LetterFrequencyPair` I can't know. But it seems you save a pointer and the `free` it later on. Probably a bug

Comment: @4386427 I'll edit the question to include the structure definitions

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the code, I get an error saying: "prev is a null pointer". However, if i remove the '= NULL' part from the node declaration, I get a compilation error that says: "prev is uninitialized".

Well, yes.  Although in a couple of places you attempt to assign to `prev->next`, nowhere do you assign to `prev` itself, unless you want to count its initializer.  When that variable is `NULL`, or when it has no defined value at all, it does not point to any object.  Under those circumstances, *there is no `prev->next`*.

It looks like you want to use `prev` to track the node preceding the current minimum. That presents a bit of a problem when the head node of your list is the current minimum.  That can be worked around by setting `prev` to `NULL` in that case and writing extra code for that special case, but it's easier and cleaner to sidestep the problem by introducing an artificial predecessor:

```
struct LetterFrequencyPair head = { .next = root };
struct LetterFrequencyPair *prev = &head;
```

Note that there is no need to allocate the head node dynamically.  For that matter, you should not need *any* dynamic allocations.  Presently, your code leaks the memory it allocates for `low` initially to point to, and the allocation for `lowest` and freeing of the original lowest node is wasteful.

It is possible that the node you end up removing turns our to be the first one.  You do not need special handling for that at the point of the deletion; it should fall out naturally in that case that `head.next` is set (via `prev`) to point to the new first node.  At the end, however, you'll want to copy it back out:

```
root = head.next;
```

If the first node is not the one that was removed, then that assignment has no net effect.

You have a lot of other issues with your code, well beyond the scope of the question, but that should get you started.